# How to get javascript object property names?

Tags: javascript, variables, html-table, ecmascript-6

I want to create a table whose header labels are known dynamically based on data object property names

Here is my code example:

```
ob = { ** name **: "Joe",
  ** age **: "22",
  ** country **: "UK"
}

table = document.createElement("table");

function createHeaders(obj) {
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  //get keys and iterate ...
  for (let key of keys) {// how to get keys ? 
    const th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerHtml = key;
    tr.appendChild(th)
  }
  return tr;
}
```

Comment: The title hurts

Comment: And yes its possible, however this is the worst thing you can do. Whywould you need that?

Comment: what title would you use?

Comment: Why would you want separate variables when you already have the data neatly inside an object?

Comment: the data above  is only a part of an object I extracted it for the question. I know how to create the "th" head without loop I wish to understand if there is any syntax in es6 that allows me to do what I try to do in the example. thanks

Comment: No there is no real syntax for it as there is no real usecase for that

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you want to generate a table from the object, you don't need temporary variables that each have a different name. Maybe show your code and ask how to solve the *actual* problem.

Comment: Considering that `let` is being scoped to each loop iteration, why on earth would you want to create 3 differently named variables? Surely they can have the same name, because they'll very soon be out of scope

Comment: I believe you want to look up the data object property names to dynamically create header labels ? If so, maybe you can use Object.keys(yourObj)

Comment: @laurent thank you I think is what I wa looking for! : )

Comment: @user184994 good point, yes I dont' really need to create a dynamic var in this code. thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `Object.keys`

```js
function createHeader(object) {
  return Object.keys(object)
  .reduce(
    (tr,key)=>{
      tr.appendChild(
        document.createElement("th")
      ).innerHTML = key;
      return tr;
    },
    document.createElement("tr")
  );
};
const table = document.createElement("table");
table.appendChild(
  createHeader({ 
    name: "Joe",
    age: "22",
    country: "UK"
  })
);
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, I put up the wrong example but I was looking for this.